# .Net Core Unit Testing With Url.Action

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, moq, url-action

I am currently running unit tests on a controller that utilizes Url.Action to get the absolute path of two different routes. I am using Moq to set up the mock Action. The test is currently failing with the message 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

[Edit - Clarifying the question]

When I debug the test, the Url shows to as a `Mock<IUrlHelper>` with an `ActionContext` property, but on the line where it calls the `Url.Action`, the `Action` property shows as null. What am I missing when setting up the `Mock<IUrlHelper>` that way the `Url.Action` doesn't come back as null?

I've checked multiple options for setting up Mock Url Actions, but nothing has seemed to work for me.

Here is the setup for the test

```
[Fact]
public async void SendGroup_PassesDetailsToNotificationService()
{
    UrlActionContext actualContext = null;
    var criteria = new NotificationCriteria { Section = 1, Subsection = 2 };
    userSvc.GetNotificationGroupReturnValue = new List<NotificationRecipient>
        {
            new NotificationRecipient{ SmsAuth = true } 
        };
    var actionContext = new ActionContext
        {
            ActionDescriptor = new ActionDescriptor(),
            RouteData = new RouteData(),
        };
    var urlHelper = new Mock<IUrlHelper>();
    urlHelper.SetupGet(h => h.ActionContext).Returns(actionContext);
    urlHelper.Setup(h => h.Action(It.IsAny<UrlActionContext>()))
             .Callback((UrlActionContext context) => actualContext = context);
    controller.Url = urlHelper.Object;

    var dummy = await controller.SendGroup(criteria);

    Assert.Same(criteria, notificationSvc.SendGroupNotificationDetailUsed);
}
```

This is the code for the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendGroup([FromBody]NotificationCriteria criteria)
{
    List<NotificationRecipient> recipients = (await userSvc.GetNotificationGroup(
                                              criteria.Section, criteria.Subsection)).ToList();

    if (!recipients.Any())
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    var uro = Url;
    var sectionUrl = Url.Action("Index", "ReportHome", new {sectionId = criteria.Section}, Request.Scheme);
    var profileUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Profile", null, Request.Scheme);
    var detail = new NotificationDetail
    {
        SectionUrl = sectionUrl,
        ProfileUrl = profileUrl,
        Recipients = recipients
    };
    try
    {
        await notificationSvc.SendGroupNotification(detail);
    }
    catch 
    {
        return StatusCode(500);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: What overload are you suggesting I use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Excuse me, I thought of the .Net framework urlhelper, which has overloads. This one does not.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski My question isn't so much as to what the error means, I am familiar with the message. I'm asking what am I missing in the Mock that is causing the `Url.Action` to come back as a null reference.